Not able to write testcase for this service
getTaskData(payload) {
   const reqUrl = `${this.wfmServicesUrl}/rest/MilestoneViewService/getMilestoneTaskData?nfid=${payload.nfid}&projectId=${payload.projectId}&now=${moment().unix()}`;
   return Axios({ method: 'get', url: reqUrl }).then(result => result.data);
}


What is your question?

I'm assuming you wish to unit test this method using jest. You have two options: 1. mock the axios instance and provide your own mock implementation as described here. 2. use a library to like nock to returning a mocked response for the http request.

I am trying to mock this function but I am not able to mock it , it is giving error undefined
